# Axios inside for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, axios

I am trying to axios requests inside a for loop but the loop is being completed even before the axios. Following is my code:

```
let findEmail = async() => {
 for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++){
    axios.post('https://email-finder.herokuapp.com/find', {
        "first_name": "Irinaa",
        "last_name": "xyz",
        "domain": "xyxz.com"
    }).then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 500){
            console.log('no email found');
        }
        else{
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('no email found ', i);
    });
      console.log('axios request done');
 }
}
```

I want the loop to wait until the request is complete and then go to increment the i variable. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: try to use promises while if you are good with observables that can help you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are in async function try using await instead of then.
It will make your for loop behave synchronously.

```
let findEmail = async () => {
      for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
        try {
          let response = await axios.post(
            "https://email-finder.herokuapp.com/find",
            {
              first_name: "Irinaa",
              last_name: "xyz",
              domain: "xyxz.com"
            }
          );
          if (response.status === 500) {
            console.log("no email found");
          } else {
            console.log(response.data);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("no email found ", i);
        }
        console.log("axios request done");
      }
    };
```

Comment: There is a major difference between making something synchronous and behaving synchronously.

Comment: Great Catch. It was my first answer, so you can say noob spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the explanation on **How to await an async call in JavaScript in a synchronous function?** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976606/how-to-await-an-async-call-in-javascript-in-a-synchronous-function) by T.J. Crowder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting to get data back, so you are waiting to status 200.
Try to add:

```
    else if(response.status === 200){
        console.log(response.data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern to consider: use an array of promises and Promise.all.

For example:

```
let findEmail = async() => {
 const promises = []
 for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++){
    const request = axios.post('https://email-finder.herokuapp.com/find', {
        "first_name": "Irinaa",
        "last_name": "xyz",
        "domain": "xyxz.com"
    }).then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 500){
            console.log('no email found');
        }
        else {
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('no email found ', i);
    });
      console.log('axios request done');
      promises.push(request)
 }
await Promise.all(promises)
}
```