# trying to understand async / await / sync in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

i know this probably has been asked before, but coming from single-threaded language for the past 20 years, i am really struggling to grasp the true nature of node. believe me, i have read a bunch of SO posts, github discussions, and articles about this.

i think i understand that each function has it's own thread type of deal. however, there are some cases where i want my code to be fully synchronous (fire one function after the other).

for example, i made 3 functions which seem to show me how node's async i/o works:

```js
function sleepA() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('sleep A')
    }, 3000)
}

function sleepB() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('sleep B')
    }, 2000)
}

function sleepC() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('sleep C')
    }, 1000)
}

sleepA()
sleepB()
sleepC()
```

this outputs the following:

```
sleep C
sleep B
sleep A
```

ok so that makes sense. node is firing all of the functions at the same time, and whichever ones complete first get logged to the console. kind of like watching horses race. node fires a gun and the functions take off, and the fastest one wins.

so now **how would i go about making these synchronous so that the order is always A, B, C**, regardless of the setTimeout number?

i've dabbled with things like `bluebird` and the `util` node library and am still kind of confused. i think this async logic is insanely powerful despite my inability to truly grasp it. php has destroyed my mind.

Comment: @Teemu - Well, unless you explicitly use something like a worker or child process. :-) "Explicitly" being the key word there.

Comment: *"how would i go about making these synchronous so that the order is always A, B, C"* Do you mean: How do I not start the B timeout until the A timeout finishes? And not start C until B finishes?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes.

Comment: JavaScript is a single-threaded language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how would i go about making these synchronous so that the order is always A, B, C

You've confirmed that what you mean by that is that you don't want to start the timeout for B until A has finished (etc.).

Here in 2021, the easiest way to do that is to use a promise-enabled wrapper for `setTimeout`, like this one:

```
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Then, make `sleepA` and such `async` functions:

```
async function sleepA() {
    await delay(3000);
    console.log("sleep A");
}

async function sleepB() {
    await delay(2000);
    console.log("sleep B");
}

async function sleepC() {
    await delay(1000);
    console.log("sleep C");
}
```

Then your code can `await` the promise each of those functions returns, which prevents the code from continuing until the promise is settled:

```
await sleepA();
await sleepB();
await sleepC();
```

You can do that inside an `async` function or (in modern versions of Node.js) at the top level of a module. You *can't* use `await` in a synchronous function, since `await` is asynchronous by nature.

> i think i understand that each function has it's own thread type of deal

No, JavaScript functions are just like those of other synchronous languages (despite its reputation, JavaScript itself is overwhelmingly synchronous; it's just used in highly-asynchronous environments and recently got some features to make that easier). More on this below.

> ok so that makes sense. node is firing all of the functions at the same time, and whichever ones complete first get logged to the console. kind of like watching horses race. node fires a gun and the functions take off, and the fastest one wins.

Close. The functions run in order, but all that each of them does is set up a timer and return. They don't wait for the timer to fire. Later, when it does fire, it calls the callback you passed into `setTimeout`.

JavaScript has a *main thread* and everything runs on that main thread unless you explicitly make it run on a worker thread or in a child process. Node.js is highly *asynchronous* (as are web browsers, the other place JavaScript is mostly used), but your JavaScript code all runs on one thread by default. There's a loop that processes "jobs." Jobs get queued by events (such as a timer firing), and then processed in order by the event loop. I go into a bit more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41976799/157247), and the Node.js documentation covers their loop [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) *(I think it's slightly out of date, but the principal hasn't changed)*.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in detail in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* covering ES2015-ES2020, and into `async`/`await` in detail in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: thank you this answer is exactly what i was looking for with my question. your clear examples and explanations are very helpful.